# Angular not rendering custom component

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, shadow-dom

I am working on a project and was updating a npm package and suddenly a custom component of the project was not rendered anymore by Angular.
The package itself has nothing to do with the component and is more like a component library which has updated many components to use the Shadow DOM view encapsulation.

The component (**folder-view.component.ts**) looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-folder-view',
  templateUrl: './folder-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./folder-view.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class FolderViewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(
    ...
  ) {}
  ...
}
```

The corresponding template (**folder-view.component.html**) like this:

```
<div *ngIf="creationMode">
  <i class="icon-gen-information-small"></i><i> {{ infoMessage }}</i>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!creationMode">
  <card>
    <card-body>
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        ...
      </div>
    </card-body>
  </card>
</div>
```

When I was rendering the component before I updated the dependency it looked like this in the DOM:
[DOM before update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci7pU.png)

After the update the DOM looked like this:
[DOM after update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3HnT.png)

In addition to not rendering the component I got a few errors telling me:
"DOMException: Failed to execute 'attachShadow' on 'Element': This element does not support attachShadow". I think this must come from the library but I can't figure out which element is meant because the debugger tells me the error root is the dispatch of an NgRx action.

Here is a picture of the Error:
[DOM error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3XgZ.png)

I am very confused and every hint is welcome! Also I am sorry if I missed details or didn't give enough information. This is my first StackOverflow question.

Comment: Which package did you update? probably has to do with wrong versions of node / npm or the package

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yeah I forgot to write that it is an internal package from the company I am doing the project for. Unfortunately I have no access to the code of this package and the guys on the other and leave me waiting so I thought I'd ask here...

Comment: Just had the exact same problem at my company ... the problem was I needed to change my node and npm versions (I'm using NVM)

Comment: Okay thank you very much I will try that. I am using NVM too... maybe the source of the problem.

Comment: I updated my version from 14.20 to 18.12 but unfortunately this didn't help...

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the reason for the error (if that helps anyone in the future) but I am still not quite sure how the error arises.

So I was using a component called `<message>` inside my component from above that was part of this external package. The creators of the package updated the component to use the shadow DOM view encapsulation and changed the tag to `<xy-message>` but still kept the old selector for compatibility (which never was a problem, only after they changed to shadow DOM).

So their selector looked like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'message, xy-message',
  ...
})
```

The weird thing is, that when changing the tag in my component to `<xy-message>` the error disappeared so there must be some kind of problem with the attachment of a shadow DOM to the `<message>` tag...